# App version 0.1.57 keeps crashing

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app, ios-app-feed

Latest version 0.1.57 is crashing left and right, such as:

- Scrolling in the feed
- Viewing messages from the inbox

---

Troubleshooting steps taken:

- Logged out
- Deleted app
- Restarted phone
- Downloaded again
- (Crashed in feed un-authenticated)
- Logged back in

---

100% consistency

Is this happening to anyone else?

Comment: Crashing like mad for me too. Will look at it when I get in if Arie hasn't already fixed it.

Comment: Dang, it crashed when tapping to read your comment from the inbox too btw. Want me to make a new bug report for that, or is this all related?

Comment: Our latest release has a pretty bad bug in it, but we are working on fixing it ASAP.

Comment: Thanks guys! No worries; that's what alpha is all about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like there was an issue in how we're posting our internal tracking events.  The quick-n-dirty hotfix to let you people enjoy the feed again is to just disable events while I get the underlying issue sorted.  I'll update here when things are more sane.

For clarity - the hotfix is just to silence internal tracking, which is hardcoded off as of **(0.1.58)**.  The crashing issue was caused during serialization of the outgoing event data.  A quick fix to that was going to entail some technical debt I didn't want to incur, so better to just kill events until a better solution is ready.

**'Nother Update:** I fixed the serialization issue for our internal analytics, and it's out now (**0.1.59+**).

Comment: seems to have stopped crashing. thanks for sprinting on this!

Comment: Dagnabbit! 0.1.59 crashes again when I select a comment from the inbox.

Comment: oooooh, fun.  That's a different bug, though.