# iOS app crashes selecting comment from inbox

Tags: bug, status-completed, global-inbox, ios-app

All was well in 0.1.56, then 0.1.57 started crashing, fixed in 0.1.58, returned in 0.1.59. All that fun happened here: [App version 0.1.57 keeps crashing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230324/app-version-0-1-57-keeps-crashing)

Selecting any comment from the inbox crashes the app.

For thoroughness, I've logged out, deleted, re-downloaded, and logged back in. No dice.

Selecting the same comment from the feed works fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You barely got this posted before I had it fixed :-)

This was another events serialization issue wherein I was stuffing an object into a dictionary that later choked the json serializer.

Thanks for the bug!  Fixed in the next build (**0.1.60+**).

Comment: Ha, sorry. When you said it was a different bug I assumed you meant I should accept the other fix and post this as a new one. Busy day!

Comment: You did the right thing - it gives us an artifact to which we can refer later.

Comment: I was also lucky enough to taste this bug. Thanks for crunching it so fast and with spicy details!

Comment: Four versions in a few hours. All seems to be good now though!

Comment: I'm trying to enjoy the fast update cycle while I can.  When we get to the AppStore, updates will move like molasses in January.

Comment: Awesome! Does that mean we can have an Achievements pane and non-modal views today too?? ;)

Comment: Hah!  Don't get ahead of yourself.  We're actually nearing a code freeze for app store release.

Comment: Will there be continued alpha-channel releases throughout beta, or exclusively App Store at that point?

Comment: @mhlester I think it's very likely that we will continue an alpha-channel concurrently with the AppStore release cycle.  The existing setup will likely stay as-is.